# Filtering DataGridView By Date Prior to Printing

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I am filtering the DataGridView by a `TIMESTAMP` column so users can determine the date of data to print. Following is how I am creating my filtered `DataGridView`. However, in order to get the correct dates for instance Feb 8, 2010 to Feb 10, 2010, I have to select one date prior so the date range has to be Feb 7, 2010 to Feb 10, 2010 to get Feb 8, 2010 to Feb 10, 2010. This is too confusing for users.

TIMESTAMP is declared as `SqlDbType.DateTime`.

Where am I screwing up?

```
private void CreateFilteredDataGridView(DataGridView dgv, string fromDate, string toDate)
{
    try
    {
        myDataSet = new DataSet();
        myDataSet.CaseSensitive = true;

        DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = myConnection;
        DataAdapter.TableMappings.Clear();
        DataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "GARAGE");
        DataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

        myDataView = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables["GARAGE"], "TIMESTAMP >= '" + 
        Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate) + "' AND TIMESTAMP <= '" + 
        Convert.ToDateTime(toDate) + "'", "TIMESTAMP", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

        dgv.DataSource = myDataView;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what time you're passing in to that method, but it's possible that the *time* portion of your DateTime is causing the problem. Make sure that the from date starts at 00:00:00 (which it should already if no time is included) and that the end date contains 23:59:59.

Comment: The dates are formatted as 2/8/2010 and 2/10/2010, respectively. No time when passed to CreateFilteredDataGridView.. When Convert.ToDateTime is called, 12 AM is appended to the end.

Comment: Right, so you're asking the DataView to include only those dates from '2/8/2010 00:00:00' to '2/10/2010 00:00:00', which would exclude _almost all_ entries from 2/10/2010 (i.e. 12:01 AM through 12:59 PM).

Comment: Gotcha.. fixed it by performing .AddHours(23.984) on the toDate and this brought it up to 23:59:02 which is precise enough I think

Comment: actually doing AddHours(23), AddHours(59), and AddSeconds(59) was better or I might miss 57 seconds of entries!